# Unable to initialize main class, Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mashape/unirest/http/exceptions/UnirestException [JAVA]

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, noclassdeffounderror, unirest

**PROBLEM**

After I run the Maven 'compile', 'install' command in Eclipse to create an executable JAR and proceed to run that JAR I get the below error

`` Error: Unable to initialize main class org.example.project.StockTracker`
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mashape/unirest/http/exceptions/UnirestException ``

I have no clue what is going on. How can I resolve this? Below are some further details. I updated the POM with the main-class information and set the classpath to 'true'.

**MAIN CLASS CODE**

```
package org.example.project;

import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;

public class StockTracker {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws UnirestException, InterruptedException  {
        HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.get("https://apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com/market/get-quotes?region=US&lang=en&symbols=TSLA")
                    .header("x-rapidapi-host", "apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com")
                    .header("x-rapidapi-key", "api-key")
                    .asString();

        //System.out.println(response.getBody());
        System.out.println("response.getBody()");
    }
}
```

**UNIREST EXCEPTION CLASS CODE**

```
package com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions;

public class UnirestException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3714840499934575734L;

    public UnirestException(Exception e) {
        super(e);
    }

    public UnirestException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }

}
```

**MANIFEST-FILE IN JAR**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.6.3
Built-By: Author
Build-Jdk: 13.0.1
Class-Path: unirest-java-1.4.9.jar httpclient-4.5.2.jar httpcore-4.4.4.j
 ar commons-logging-1.2.jar commons-codec-1.9.jar httpasyncclient-4.1.1.
 jar httpcore-nio-4.4.4.jar httpmime-4.5.2.jar json-20160212.jar
Main-Class: org.example.project.StockTracker
```

Comment: Is a dependency with the UnirestException assempled into your jar?

Comment: here is the path..com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions. This specific exception class is embedded within the unirest jar which I call as a dependency in my POM. The actual unirest JAR executable itself is not in my JAR but rather it is decalred in my manifest file...

Comment: @IlyaLysenko OK I think I partially solved it. I copied the physical JAR dependencies into my 'target' folder which houses my JAR executable. Running the program like this worked. However, is there a way I can embed these dependencies within my JAR file to avoid doing this? Is there a maven command for it?

Comment: The `mvn package` command have to assemble a jar with dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @IlyaLysenko! I used mvn clean compile assembly:single and it did the trick! Just needed to update the POM file and all dependencies were inserted into only 1 JAR.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of @IlyaSenko I managed to figure it out. I needed to include all my JAR dependencies within my actual JAR as opposed to simply declaring the dependency within my POM file. I updated my POM with the below to achieve this..

```
<plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>org.example.project.StockTracker</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then executed the following command using Maven "**mvn clean compile assembly:single**" which bundled all the JARs into one executable JAR. JAR worked after that.